# What font does Vitabot use in their logo?

Tags: font-identification

This is a font that a client would like to use on his site that I'm designing. Can someone help me determine what the font is?

Here is a logo with the font I am looking for:
 [image: Vitabot Logo]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That font looks like [Skia](http://new.myfonts.com/fonts/apple/skia/), but the horizontal bar on the I in the logo is custom.